# Dart Future.value vs async

Tags: dart, async-await, future

Is there any benefit to using `Future.value` as opposed to returning a value in an `async` function? E.g.

```dart
Future<String> foo() async => "bar";
// OR
Future<String> foo() => Future.value("bar");
```

I prefer the `async` option as it's more succinct, but I can't see any benefits beyond that.

Comment: The `async` version is syntactic sugar for the non-`async` version.  In general, prefer using `async`; it's clearer and less error-prone.

Comment: The `Future.value` is from a time before the `async` keyword. Just if you are wondering why it is there and not recommended.